# How to pass JSON to vue-treeselect

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@riophae/vue-treeselect

in a Laravel application.

I want to be able to pass its options from my Controller.

I have a single file component which implements the tree and I am trying to pass the options in as a prop:

```
<bss-tree options="{{$options}}">
</bss-tree>
```

Here is the controller code:

```
$options = "{
                        id: 'bikes',
                        label: 'Bikes'
                        }";


return view('users.changeGroup', compact('options'));
```

The error I get from this is:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "options". Expected Array, got String.
```

What should I be passing and how?

Answer (score 0):

I have this working by passing the options as a string and then doing this:

```
computed: {
            options: function(){
                return JSON.parse(this.optionsString);
            }
        },
```